# I was using a <Image /> tag in Next.js using a link of an image and it was showing an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, next.js, frontend

I have tried it several times but the error was the same.
I have also created the next.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    images: {
      domains: ['link.papareact.com', ],
    },
  };


Error: Invalid src prop (https://links.papareact.com/ua6) on `next/image`, hostname "links.papareact.com" is not configured under images in your `next.config.js`
See more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host
```

any solution for this asap.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your application to get the config applied?

Comment: Yes, I had tried several times

Comment: link or links? You have added `link.papareact.com`

Comment: I have also tried for links.papareact.com. the the error was the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```js
module.exports = {
    images: {
      domains: ['link.papareact.com/*']
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    domains: ['links.papareact.com']
  }
};
```

It will be "links" instead of link.